# Adding a title after spreadsheet and macros are written

Tags: excel, vba

I have been making a spreadsheet with sorting macros for my work for about the past week. I finally finished up the coding(98% of it) and my boss now tells me I need a title at the top of the spreadsheet when it prints. All of the codes I have written error when I shift the data down in order to add a title in row 1. Is there a way to add a title without having this happen? I'm a novice with VBA all around and recieved a decent amount of help with this project so bear with my ignorance please! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Page Header settings to add a title, without affecting the rows themselves.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a worksheet object called `sheet`, you can set its header in code using the `PageSetup` property:

```
sheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "Centered Title"
```

You can also control the left & right headers and center/left/right footers like this.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for VBA. Simply add a header to your document. Go to Insert, Header and Footer.

Comment: There is no need for VBA for anything VBA can do if you're willing to do it manually every time. I think the OP's idea is to *automate* these things.

Comment: @retailcoder: why -1? the question clearly implies that this is a one off situation.